# Issues with DI when splitting up a CRUD Repository

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I've had the idea of breaking down my ICrudRepository into 4 individual repositories: `ICreatableRepository`, `IReadableRepository` etc, one for each operation type. Each with their own implementation which will carry out the operation. I'd like to do this because I may have a repository that I only want to have read access, in which case I would only implement `IReadableRepository<T, TId>`, rather than implement `ICrudRepository` with a load of methods not implemented.

```
public interface ICreatableRepository<T>
{
    Task Create(T model);
}
```

So far so good, however consider the following:

```
public interface IMyNewCrudRepository<T, TId> : 
    ICreatableRepository<T>,
    IReadableRepository<T, TId>,
    IUpdatableRepository<T>,
    IDeletableRepository<TId>
{}

public abstract class BaseCrudRepository<TModel, TId> : IMyNewCrudRepository<TModel, TId>
{
    private readonly ICreatableRepository<TModel> _creatableRepository;
    private readonly IReadableRepository<TModel, TId> _readableRepository;
    private readonly IUpdatableRepository<TModel> _updatableRepository;
    private readonly IDeletableRepository<TId> _deletableRepository;

    protected BaseCrudRepository(ICreatableRepository<TModel> creatableRepository, IReadableRepository<TModel, TId> readableRepository, IUpdatableRepository<TModel> updatableRepository, IDeletableRepository<TId> deletableRepository)
    {
        _creatableRepository = creatableRepository;
        _readableRepository = readableRepository;
        _updatableRepository = updatableRepository;
        _deletableRepository = deletableRepository;
    }

    public async Task Create(TModel model)
    {
        await _creatableRepository.Create(model);
    }

    //other implemented methods
}
```

This would be a shortcut as such, to save me from having to implement all 4 of the Interfaces and cluttering a repository when I **do** want every CRUD operation.

I thought that this was great until I thought about how to inject it. As `BaseCrudRepository` relies on all 4 individual crud implementations from DI, will I now have to DI these based on the model?

I suppose one option would be to create these in the base's constructor rather than have them injected, but would this be an anti pattern?

Comment: You could split them into 2 types. `ReadOnlyRepository` and `Repository` where `Repository` has Create, Update, and Delete and also inherits from `ReadOnlyRepository`. It would definitely simplify some things.

Comment: I still don't quite get what's the benefit of the delegation from the base abstract implementation to 4 different abstractions. What do you plan to inject there in an actual implementation that inherits from the `BaseCrudRepository`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Sorry I didn't make that clear. I would inject a repository class that inherits `BaseCrudRepository` and implements it's own Interface (for it's own specific requirements), it's own interface would implement `IMyNewCrudRepository`

Comment: Sounds like abstraction over abstraction over abstraction...

Comment: Do you need separate repositories or just different interfaces? What if you just have one repository that implements read-only and writable interfaces, or put a read-only wrapper around your existing repository?

Comment: Still don't get it, unfortunately. You have a base abstract class that you have to inherit from (since it's abstract). You will have multiple concrete classes then. But this abstract class has to be fed with other concrete implementations, still implementing the same interface. The abstraction acts like a proxy from one layer to another layer it delegates to. Are you sure you don't overengineer this?

Comment: use [Composition instead of Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

If your concrete repository class implements this interface:

```
public interface IMyNewCrudRepository<T, TId> : 
    ICreatableRepository<T>,
    IReadableRepository<T, TId>,
    IUpdatableRepository<T>,
    IDeletableRepository<TId>
{}
```

then you've already accomplished the abstraction and interface segregation I think you're looking for. Separating the repositories into different classes is likely unnecessary. Separating the repositories into multiple classes, each implementing a different interface, and then recombining them into one class which implements all of the interfaces is almost certainly unnecessary. Why take them apart just to put them back together?

```
public class NeedsToReadFromRepository<Thing>
{
    private readonly IReadableRepository<Thing, Guid> _repository;

    public NeedsToReadFromRepository(IReadableRepository<Thing, Guid> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

The consumer only depends on the interface, so it doesn't matter if one class implements all of the interfaces. There may at times be a valid reason to split up a class (Single Responsibility Principle) but you don't need to split up the class to get the benefit of the Interface Segregation Principle.

And, as mentioned in a comment, if this needs to be split up at all, having a separate interface for every single operation may be overkill.

If you do split it up more granularly then you have more DI to register. I would never suggest having fewer interfaces than you need to avoid extra DI registration. But maybe it's something to consider before getting extremely granular.